# Mongodb document fields order

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have a question - is there a way to rearrange the order of fields in an existing mongodb document?

My case is that I have a document that aggregates some numeric values. On insertion it would be:

```
{
  "alexander": {"quantity":27},
  "beatrix": {"quantity": 28},
  "appolo": {"quantity": 5}
}
```

Now there is a process that is receiving new quantities for those users and aggregates them by addition.
So after some time we will have values like:

```
{
  "alexander": {"quantity":30},
  "beatrix": {"quantity": 40},
  "appolo": {"quantity": 31}
}
```

It would be cool If I could return the users ordered by the quantity value, so something like:

```
{
  "beatrix": {"quantity": 40},
  "appolo": {"quantity": 31},
  "alexander": {"quantity":30}
}
```

I read that mongodb is preserving insertion order. I didn't find any way to dynamically specify the order of fields in the document. Could you give me a hint if this is doable?

UPDATE:

I'm looking for things that I can achieve in mongodb console that would be client technology agnostic.

Cheers

Comment: Yes it is possible But is also entirely dependant on the code you are using that you have not included in your question. Please include the code so an explanation can be given. I will also prefix this with that if this is indeed a single aggregated result or any processing is "per document", then you are better sorting this out in client code after the db operations instead as it is much more efficient to do so.

Comment: I'm using mongoid with ruby.Which part of code do you need, the retrieval, the update part?

Comment: Wel  the "whatever you are doing to get to the result part" would be a nice start. But please read the comment in full first, as it mostly makes sense to do such reordering in the client. For what it is worth, and I personally see little worth in it at all.

Comment: Cheers, I didn't read the last part, that's true :-P For now I have a simple spring MongoTemplate in spring that returns me a list of Map<String, Object> objects for specified query criteria. I know that the server-side sorting is an doable option, but I want to make sure that there is no mongodb side mechanism that can be used to keep things simple.

Comment: Well actually great big "Oh Dear!" as `Map` is ordered by key. But if you used something else *"Think insertion order map!"* then you at least get results in that order. But seriously this is a client code ask that you should not be asking of the database. MongoDB is a "database" afterall and plays nicely with "data" being the "values" present on the keys. Don't ask for "server side" key re-ordering, as that means JavaScript processing on the server. Which should translate to: `"ask" == "bad"`

Comment: I get your point, but in many cases db providers add features that simplify that kind of things. For instance in this case if I was be able to rely on the db support for ordering I would be able to rely also on the fact that mongodb is caching entries in memory so I wouldn't have to introduce separate cache on the client side to store ordered values. I will update the question to be more specific.

Comment: Making this really simple. If you expect "keys" to be ordered by their values then you need "JavaScript" processing and therefore mapReduce to get the result from the server. You probably don't need this really so just do it in the client. If you really do need this then instead structure like `[{ "name": "alexander", "quantity": 40 }]` within an "array" instead. Then you have a mechanism for "sorting" that can be efficiently done on the server without JavaScript processing or other client concerns. Learn to take good advice,

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right, remodeling would be a solution, mongo has operators for arrays, I will wait a little bit longer, maybe there will be someone else that will look at things from different perspective.

Comment: Or you could learn the lesson and move on. BTW. Who do you think just gave you a perspective? Perhaps clicking on the username link here and viewing a profile might give you some insight.

Comment: Ok, I get the point :P Thanks.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I'm not sure who you're supposed to be, but this is pretty cringey.